# Create batch file to stop services - The service name is invalid

Tags: windows-services, batch-file

I've noticed that whenever I start a service (by starting a batch file through cmd) with multiple words separated by a space, the cmd prompts that the service name is invalid

Working batch file:

```
@echo off
net start AdobeARMService
```

Not working batch file:

```
@echo off
net start Sample Windows Service
```

How do I run services with spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I have it working. Just put quotation marks on services with multiple words..

Sample:

```
@echo off
net start "Sample Windows Service"
```